# how to send multiple commands to a file in cron?

Tags: php, parameters, cron

I have a file that is having some multiple dynamic parameters.I want to send these parameters at the time of writing a file in main cron file. Something like this ->

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /a/b/c.php parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 parameter4
```

Now i tried working this up but my file is not executing.
What im concerned about is that how will my php file will fetch these parameters ??
And how will i write this command when there is only 2 parameters to be passes parameter1 and parameter4???
and how will my cron and php will recognoze that which parameter is for which data and all??
please advice!!

Answer (score 0):

```
*/15 * * * * "/usr/bin/php /a/b/c.php parameter1 parameter2 parameter3 parameter4"
```

maybe...

also you can pass it as a query string? p1=123&p2=432&p3=456
within the script you can just do a parse_string to convert it into an array...

Comment: but how can i send query string with this kind of file calling : /home/abc/xyz/ert.php 
???
query string is possible in http:// kind of urls but how will i write it in path format???

Answer (score 0):

In this case it will be `$argv` array in your script with those parameters.

Also you can make an executable file with contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?
    require('yourscript.php');
```

And make it executable with `chmod +x thisfile`. Just not to pass your file name to php interpreter in crontab.

Answer (score 0):

The way you need to go about making this script work is the following:

In the cron script set the parameters to each be query strings.  For example, set `p1=1234` as parameter1, etc.

Within the PHP script, you will need to reference the [$argv](http://www.php.net/manual/kr/reserved.variables.argv.php) array to get the parameters passed in.

$argv[1] will be parameter1, $argv[2] is parameter2, and so forth.

You can identify which parameter is which by using the explode command to separate the key from the value:

```
for($x=1; $x < $argc; $x++) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $argv[1]);
    $paramarray[$key] = $value;
}
```